# Sitecore Commerce installation error in opening Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework

I am installing Sitecore Commerce 9 on site with Sitecore 9.0 Update 2. I am using SIF to install Sitecore Commerce. I get the following error and it interrupts the commerce installation.

> Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\sc902commercedeploy\assets\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3\tools\VSToolsPath\Web\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

**Note** - I have the file in the correct place under MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3 folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to unblock that file as Windows thinks it is suspicious (as you have downloaded it from internet in "zip" file).

Right click on the file and on General tab check "Unblock" on the bottom of the screen. Click on "OK" or "Apply" afterwards:

[image]

More useful tips can be found in my article dedicated to installation of Sitecore Commerce 9 -> https://tothecore.sk/2018/07/16/installing-sitecore-experience-commerce-sxc-9-0-update-2-9-0-2/

Answer (score 4):

In my case both the above solution is not working. So I have copied from the below path and works perfect.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that you have extracted the dll out of the nuget package, your SIF script can't link through to the nuget package itself.

If you open up the Nuget packages, you will find the dll at: **\tools\VSToolsPath\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll**

You can drop this dll on to disk and then point your SIF script directly to it, e.g. the line in my SIF install script that points to it, looks like:

```
MergeToolFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "C:\Sitecore Repo\Modules\Sitecore.Commerce.2018.07-2.2.126\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"
```

Comment: Rob,Thank you for the answer but like i said, i have extracted it into a file and pointed it to the correct path.

Answer (score -2):

I've faced the same problem, I've checked for the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll using properties & found that this dll was blocked, so just checked the box against UnBlock option & also checked for SIF version, I was having 2 SIFs installed. so removed all & reinstalled 2.1.0. by using the command..

Get-Module SitecoreInstallFramework -List

Uninstall-Module SitecoreInstallFramework

Install-Module SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 2.1.0

Comment: Why do you need to reinstall SIF? This problem is not related to SIF at all. @Rob or myself already question with proper fixes